# Working with large checks if elif

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I am writing a script that will automatically work with MySQL. I do not understand how to implement this:

```
MYSQL_RESULT=mysql -u LOGIN -pPASS -D "TABLE_NAME" -e "SQL request";
for i in $MYSQL_RESULT; do
    if [ $i -le 100 ]
        then r_kills = '100';

    elif [ $i -le 500 ]
        then r_kills = '100';

    elif [ $i -le 1000 ]
        then r_kills = '500';

    echo $r_kills;
    fi
done;
```

```
sh: 21: cron.rankme.sh: r_kills: not found
```

Comment: What's the expected and actual outcome?

Comment: Hi, check out [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question to receive more attention. :)

Comment: @karl-richter ,in php it works, since php works slowly, I decided to rewrite it to the shell.

example php code:
if ( $i <= 100 ) $type = '100';
elseif ( $i <= 500) $type = '100';

Comment: @VladEffect That doesn't explain anything related to the question.

Comment: @KarlRichter Cut all $i with a smaller range and give a fixed result

Comment: That's probably one of expected and actual outcome, but giving only one is as useless as giving none.

Comment: @VladEffect u don't need `fi` in each elif checking, just need it at last.

Comment: Edit the question please.  Code in comments is unreadable.  Also it avoids new readers from having to go through all the comments to figure out WTH your are talking about...

Comment: @VladEffect Variable assignments in Bash mustn't have spaces around `=`.

Comment: @VladEffect `MYSQL_RESULT=mysql -u …` doesn't do what you think it does. You'll want some `$(…)` around the command.

Comment: You have 2 times '= 100' (which should be =100) in your code, while the one ( -le 100) is a subcase of the other (-le 500). That doesn't make much sense.

Comment: All semicolons except the one in the `for` line are useless and should be removed.

Comment: Use shellcheck.net to check your code.

Answer (score 0):

This is an invalid assignment. You may not have spaces in front of or behind the equal sign in the shell - in contrast to most programming languages I know:

```
if [ $i -le 100 ]
        then r_kills = '100';

if [ $i -le 100 ]
        then r_kills=100;
```

Note that there isn't a way to distinguish numbers and text in the shell, either. Single- and double quotes are only used to mask special characters, including whitespace.

The message

```
sh: 21: cron.rankme.sh: r_kills: not found
```

mislead me to think, you used something which is not in the path, but in reality, the tokenizer had decided, that `r_kills = '100'` is a programm call to r_kills with two parameters, '=' and '100'.

The first line - without knowing mysql very well,

```
MYSQL_RESULT=mysql -u LOGIN -pPASS -D "TABLE_NAME" -e "SQL request";
```

most probably has to be

```
MYSQL_RESULT=$(mysql -u LOGIN -pPASS -D "TABLE_NAME" -e "SQL request";)
```

or

```
MYSQL_RESULT=($(mysql -u LOGIN -pPASS -D "TABLE_NAME" -e "SQL request";))
```

to create an array, since you try to iterate over the variable.

Comment: root@linux:~# ***yash cron.rankme.sh***
_[: `kills' is not a valid integer_